# Connecting to AKS API (via HTTP) from an Azure VM

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-service

I would like to connect to AKS API from a script on Azure VM inorder to scrape some metrics, check some stats, etc of the cluster.

Is there any approach (like an Azure policy or role and attaching it to VM) other than creating an user in azure AD or a service account in the AKS with clusterRole bound to it and referencing the certs/tokens from VM?
Thank you

Comment: Why not just use the built in monitoring solutions for AKS already? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-analyze https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-enable-existing-clusters

Comment: We have organizational reasons to use an isolated monitoring solution. Well, not just about monitoring, if there is any azure function or any client that wants to talk to AKS API, Is there a way to give it access via Policies?